# How to remove duplicates from the list of tuples?

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Rn':['G1','G2','G3','G4'],'G1':['x','a','c','a'],'G2':['a','x','c','a'],'G3':['c','c','x','c'],'G4':['a','a','c','x']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('Rn')
locations = [(df[col][df[col].eq('c')].index[i], col) for col in df.columns for i in range(len(df[col][df[col].eq('c')].index))]
print(locations)

Output:

[('G3', 'G1'), ('G3', 'G2'), ('G1', 'G3'), ('G2', 'G3'), ('G4', 'G3'), ('G3', 'G4')]
```

How to remove duplicates from the output? 
I have tired

```
Set()
```

But it's not working

Comment: Do you mean `locations = set(locations)`?

Comment: What have you tried with the Set().  If you put the list of items you print in a set, then there will be no duplicates in the set